# how to calculate Mean IoU in yoloV5 object detection model?

Tags: deep-learning, artificial-intelligence, object-detection, yolo, yolov5

I want to evaluate an object detection model with the **meanIoU** metric with the yolov5 algorithm. Yolov5 doesn't have a **meanIoU** evaluation metric.
Is **meanIoU** a valid metric for object detection?
How can I implement it in the validation phase of the model with Python in yolov5?

Answer (score 0):

In Yolo5 you must implement the IoU or other metrics that you want the Yolo's loss function.
Because of the unique and dynamic output of the Yolo model, you have to implement this metric in the loss function.

Comment: I don't want to optimize the model based on the menaIoU I just want to evaluate it. Is meanIoU a valid metric for object detection? or Its just used in semantic segmentation

Comment: it is valid and you can use in the both use cases and I didn't say optimize it. I just said you can calculate it in the loss function and show it during training and not use it.
its up to you whether use it to calculate loss or just show it.